# Can anyone help me with the python code game?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import random

mobs = {
  "enemys": {
    "Stray Dog": {
      "health": 3,
      "strenth": 2,
      "dexterity": 1,
    },
    "Hobo": {
      "health": 4,
      "strenth": 2,
      "dexterity": 2,
    },
    "Mugger": {
      "health": 5,
      "strenth": 2,
      "dexterity": 2,
    },
    "Cop": {
      "health": 7,
      "strenth": 3,
      "dexterity": 2,
    },
    "Ninja": {
      "health": 9,
      "strenth": 2,
      "dexterity": 4,
    }
  },
  "Player": {
    "phealth": 100,
    "pstrength": 1,
    "pdexterity": 1,
    "pconstitution": 1,
    },
}

levelrn = 3
phealth = mobs["Player"]["phealth"]
pstrength = mobs["Player"]["pstrength"]
pdexterity = mobs["Player"]["pdexterity"]
pconstitution = mobs["Player"]["pconstitution"]
ehealth = 0
estrength = 0
edexterity = 0
curenemy = ""


def level():
  global levelrn
  global pconstitution
  global pstrength
  global pdexterity
  global curenemy
  global ehealth
  global edexterity
  global estrength
  global phealth
  levelrn =3
  print("Level " + str(levelrn) + "\n---------")
  print("Health: " + str(phealth))
  print("Strenth: " + str(pstrength))
  print("Dexterity: " + str(pdexterity))
  print("Constitution: " + str(pconstitution))
  if levelrn == 1:
    curenemy = "Stray Dog"
  elif levelrn == 2:
    curenemy = "Hobo"
  elif levelrn == 3:
    curenemy = "Mugger"
  elif levelrn == 4:
    curenemy = "Cop"
  elif levelrn == 5:
    curenemy = "Ninja"
  estrength = mobs["enemys"][curenemy]["strenth"]
  edexterity = mobs["enemys"][curenemy]["dexterity"]
  ehealth = mobs["enemys"][curenemy]["health"]
  print("You find your self pitted against a " + curenemy + ".")
  print("Choose One\n----------\nAttack!")
  userin = input()
  if userin == "Attack" or "A" or "a" or "attack":
    if pdexterity > edexterity:
      pgdex()
    else:
      pldex()


def pgdex():
  pdamage = random.randrange(1, 3)
  print("You dealt " + str(pdamage) + " damage!")
  global ehealth
  ehealth -= pdamage
  pldex()


def pldex():
  if mobs["enemys"][curenemy]["strenth"] == estrength:
    edamage = random.randrange(estrength - 1, estrength + 1)
    print("You took " + str(edamage) + " damage!")
    global phealth
    phealth -= edamage
    print("Hp: " + phealth)
    pgdex()


level()
```

This is the output of the code:

```
Level 1
---------
Health: 100
Strength: 1
Dexterity: 0
Constitution: 1
You find yourself pitted against a Stray Dog
Choose One
---------
Attack
```

It is supposed to run the level at 3 and the "Stray Dog" is supposed to be a "Mugger".

Also the dexterity and constitution and strength arent changing.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al

Comment: This code has 9 times more `global` statements than I used in all of my programs in almost 20 years of using Python. Functions should get all the information they need via parameters and return values with `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to change line 103 to **print("Hp: " + str(phealth))** or the script won't work.

Then, you have to change functions **pgdex** and **pldex** because they invoke each other and create an infinite loop which results in RecursionError.

Besides that your code seems right. I get an output of lvl 3 and fight agains Mugger when I start it.

To handle RecursionError:

```
def foo1():
  pdamage = random.randrange(1, 3)
  print("You dealt " + str(pdamage) + " damage!")
  global ehealth
  ehealth -= pdamage

def foo2():
  if mobs["enemys"][curenemy]["strenth"] == estrength:
    edamage = random.randrange(estrength - 1, estrength + 1)
    print("You took " + str(edamage) + " damage!")
    global phealth
    phealth -= edamage
    print("Hp: " + str(phealth))

def pgdex():
  foo1()
  foo2()

def pldex():
  foo2()
  foo1()
```

Comment: in other words, the O.P. is likely running another version of the file than the one they are editing.

Comment: What are you running it on?

Comment: Python 3.10.6 but it shouldn't matter

Comment: How would i change it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the last `print` statement of the code. Should be

```
print("Hp: " + str(phealth))
```

I ran the code after fixing that bug, and this is printed:

```
Level 3
---------
Health: 100
Strenth: 1
Dexterity: 1
Constitution: 1
You find your self pitted against a Mugger.
Choose One
----------
Attack!
```

which I think is what you want. However, a new issue arises because the game will keep running after reaching negative HP.

Comment: The new issue isn't the problem; the "game" is still being developed